# Получение из sender'a кнопку

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

суть вопроса такова, получение из `private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)` кнопку для дальнейшего её перемещения на место другой кнопки.
Делаю следующие действия `Button buttonc = (Button)sender;` для преобразования `sender` в `Button`. Но, выходит следующая ошибка : не существует подходящего определяемого пользователем преобразования из `"System::Object^"` в `"System::Windows::Form::Button"`, гуглил но ничего таки не нашёл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь преоброзаовать укзатель в экземпляр объекта.
`Button` в C#  эквивалентен `Button^` в C++cli, a `Button` в C++cli это экземпляр объекта в автоматической памяти (на стеке) что вообще невозможно в C#.

Вероятно, вы хотели написать:

```
Button^ buttonc = safe_cast<Button^>(sender);
```